# Signed license key verification with RSA public key in Python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#1

Disclaimer: I am terrible at cryptography and I understand very little about RSA or cryptographic verification.

I need to verify an signed license in Python. I used "RSA PKCS1 v1.5 padding, with a SHA256 digest". The background information is that I am trying to distribute software with https://keygen.sh.

Basically, binary software is installed on a server and verifies that the license file stored on the server is genuine. To do so, the software has access to my RSA public key. I have a piece of code working in Node.js, coming from [the official keygen documentation](https://keygen.sh/docs/validating-licenses/), and I am trying to port it to Python, without success. I have chosen to use the cryptodome library, but I'm open to other options.

Here is the working piece of code, in Node.js:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtmwlw+mDo2ZVBlRXa7Em\ncj7cVrlwnwrIPC+Ij5KpltadJfwvRFvCr37USJvkc+FIND2dKk2mmbY32cvtxl3F\nYLpjRwwlFuajbP8ZEdJl1YJyJDnLlKHWEfTSvTzZhpT939yjuBKoZ9A+wiIQ9tzY\nF/ytb9zwPkOF7/XmPAaukah5xRgwsb3fo7E0CsBQuHZxFX83+nfdZ/60MWpSCWL6\nAjNWDEmoLFEHVRm69+lwXTW51wojfurZy/wUw42sciHLV5A8mz7gJJGO5y+sGzzD\nM5VxtmLz51Fl1Rl3fMzUAjPK77i9UDWo11EuNPrzMAgjmuuMLfpIDMlMR3n/ZsW7\nXwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
const key = 'somerandomkey'
const encodedSignature = "oMTrvIz3IX4kre5UTzvkzCn712wulPvl9knSYBduYcGsX2W703zWMC9ZVepDytxLdpUIiCUtx6wx5OzmLx3rTzgaKqptrbf2wYHrCIPBgrhcHdJ3fLJRh8ASC_NdLK6i1jC_bEAq84d7QNLlTPC20aCmNLdxEJFy-DValGG0iFdxx6n6-Vp5oL8jSyWubAvBSqEQ4ubptcYirxpbDdC4DRpNzBuA48DGxWg6Pxq5HdGZWKS05iohNlrFkW-K8NJYHuLKszT0FN5UWcghx1oklagCm72aDvXm3CzKL2id7yL78X_V69JYsExx3fjRsU0pUe-f5lzKLB_HLTAdc0e1gQ=="

const verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256')
verifier.write(key)
verifier.end()

const ok = verifier.verify(public_key, encodedSignature, 'base64')
if (ok) {
  console.log('License key is valid!')
} else {
  console.log('License key is invalid!')
}
```

Running this piece of code (`nodejs verify.js`) prints `License key is valid!`.

And here is the failing code, in Python:

```
import base64

# pip install pycryptodome
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15
import Crypto.Util.Padding

public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtmwlw+mDo2ZVBlRXa7Em\ncj7cVrlwnwrIPC+Ij5KpltadJfwvRFvCr37USJvkc+FIND2dKk2mmbY32cvtxl3F\nYLpjRwwlFuajbP8ZEdJl1YJyJDnLlKHWEfTSvTzZhpT939yjuBKoZ9A+wiIQ9tzY\nF/ytb9zwPkOF7/XmPAaukah5xRgwsb3fo7E0CsBQuHZxFX83+nfdZ/60MWpSCWL6\nAjNWDEmoLFEHVRm69+lwXTW51wojfurZy/wUw42sciHLV5A8mz7gJJGO5y+sGzzD\nM5VxtmLz51Fl1Rl3fMzUAjPK77i9UDWo11EuNPrzMAgjmuuMLfpIDMlMR3n/ZsW7\nXwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
license_key = b'somerandomkey'

encoded_license_signature = """oMTrvIz3IX4kre5UTzvkzCn712wulPvl9knSYBduYcGsX2W703zWMC9ZVepDytxLdpUIiCUtx6wx5OzmLx3rTzgaKqptrbf2wYHrCIPBgrhcHdJ3fLJRh8ASC_NdLK6i1jC_bEAq84d7QNLlTPC20aCmNLdxEJFy-DValGG0iFdxx6n6-Vp5oL8jSyWubAvBSqEQ4ubptcYirxpbDdC4DRpNzBuA48DGxWg6Pxq5HdGZWKS05iohNlrFkW-K8NJYHuLKszT0FN5UWcghx1oklagCm72aDvXm3CzKL2id7yL78X_V69JYsExx3fjRsU0pUe-f5lzKLB_HLTAdc0e1gQ=="""
license_signature = base64.b64decode(encoded_license_signature)
# Padding: none of these solutions work
# license_signature = Crypto.Util.Padding.pad(license_signature, 8, style='pkcs7')
# license_signature = Crypto.Util.Padding.pad(license_signature, 8, style='iso7816')
# license_signature = Crypto.Util.Padding.pad(license_signature, 8, style='x923')
# Custom zero-padding (doesn't work either)
#license_signature = (8 - len(license_signature) % 8)*bytes([0]) + license_signature
#license_signature = license_signature + (8 - len(license_signature) % 8)*bytes([0])

rsa_public_key = RSA.import_key(public_key)
signature = Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15.new(rsa_public_key)

license_hash = SHA256.new(data=license_key)
print(signature.verify(license_hash, license_signature))
```

Running this piece of code (`python3 verify.py`) raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "verify.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(signature.verify(license_hash, license_signature))
  File "/home/user/venvs/tutor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Signature/pkcs1_15.py", line 111, in verify
    raise ValueError("Invalid signature")
ValueError: Invalid signature
```

This corresponds to a [signature length error](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/v3.7.3/lib/Crypto/Signature/pkcs1_15.py#L111):

```
# Step 1
if len(signature) != k:
    raise ValueError("Invalid signature")
```

I assumed that this was caused by incorrect padding, so I made different attempts at signature padding that you can see in my piece of code, none of which work. But at least, they allow me to move beyond the first step of signature verification. I am now stuck in the [fourth and final step](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/v3.7.3/lib/Crypto/Signature/pkcs1_15.py#L137):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "verify.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(signature.verify(license_hash, license_signature))
  File "/home/user/venvs/tutor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Signature/pkcs1_15.py", line 137, in verify
    raise ValueError("Invalid signature")
ValueError: Invalid signature
```

Any idea how to solve this? I'm ready to use something different than cryptodome, if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your signature is in base64url instead of standard base64. I presume the latter is the culprit. So you need to replace `-` with `+` and `_` with `/`. You may need to pad with `=` up to the next multiple of 4 base64 characters, depending on the base64 encoder (here it doesn't seem needed).

It is better to use a base64url decoder of course, which is more performant as you don't need character replacement, which will in turn often requires string copies.

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEES! Indeed, the following works: `license_signature = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encoded_signature)`. No padding is necessary.
Thank you SO MUCH.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the founder of Keygen. This is a lack of proper documentation on my end, which I will correct. Like [Maarten mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54895909/3247081), the signed contents of the license key (which contains 2 parts: the key payload and its signature) are base64url encoded using [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648), a URL-safe version of base64 which is supported in most programming languages (but not always). This base64url encoding scheme is slightly different than normal base64 encoding, as outlined in Maarten's answer.

Most programming languages will have a separate function for decoding URL base64 encoded values,
but if not, like Maarten outlines in his answer, you can simply replace all "`-`" base64 chars with "`+`", and all "`_`" chars with "`/`".

Here's a full example of verifying a license key signed with RSA-SHA256 using PKCS1 v1.5 padding:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
import base64

# This should be your Keygen account's public key
PUBLIC_KEY = \
"""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtmwlw+mDo2ZVBlRXa7Em
cj7cVrlwnwrIPC+Ij5KpltadJfwvRFvCr37USJvkc+FIND2dKk2mmbY32cvtxl3F
YLpjRwwlFuajbP8ZEdJl1YJyJDnLlKHWEfTSvTzZhpT939yjuBKoZ9A+wiIQ9tzY
F/ytb9zwPkOF7/XmPAaukah5xRgwsb3fo7E0CsBQuHZxFX83+nfdZ/60MWpSCWL6
AjNWDEmoLFEHVRm69+lwXTW51wojfurZy/wUw42sciHLV5A8mz7gJJGO5y+sGzzD
M5VxtmLz51Fl1Rl3fMzUAjPK77i9UDWo11EuNPrzMAgjmuuMLfpIDMlMR3n/ZsW7
XwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

# This should be the license key that you're cryptographically verifying
LICENSE_KEY = \
"""c29tZXJhbmRvbWtleQ==.oMTrvIz3IX4kre5UTzvkzCn712wulPvl9knSYBduYcGsX2W703zWMC9ZVepDytxLdpUIiCUtx6wx5OzmLx3rTzgaKqptrbf2wYHrCIPBgrhcHdJ3fLJRh8ASC_NdLK6i1jC_bEAq84d7QNLlTPC20aCmNLdxEJFy-DValGG0iFdxx6n6-Vp5oL8jSyWubAvBSqEQ4ubptcYirxpbDdC4DRpNzBuA48DGxWg6Pxq5HdGZWKS05iohNlrFkW-K8NJYHuLKszT0FN5UWcghx1oklagCm72aDvXm3CzKL2id7yL78X_V69JYsExx3fjRsU0pUe-f5lzKLB_HLTAdc0e1gQ=="""

# Split license key to obtain key and signature, then decode urlbase64 encoded values
enc_key, enc_sig = LICENSE_KEY.split(".")
key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc_key)
sig = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc_sig)

# Verify the key's signature
pub_key = RSA.importKey(PUBLIC_KEY)
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(pub_key)
digest = SHA256.new(data=key)

print(
  verifier.verify(digest, sig)
)
```

I've updated Keygen's documentation to clarify all of these things, as well as to provide better examples on how to cryptographically verify the license.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Note that you should probably import pkcs1_15 instead of PKCS1_v1_5: https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py#L31
Btw, I did send an email to Keygen support prior to posting here ;)